# Designing mercury in glass thermometer

Tags: thermodynamics

Should the stem of a mercury-in-glass thermometer be marked off in equal
divisions for equal temperature intervals if the coefficient of thermal expansion of glass is assumed to be strictly constant?

Now this question comes as a "food for thought" from Callen after showing that the coefficient of thermal expansion for mercury $\alpha_{Hg}$ is constant over some temperature range of interest. I am trying to think about how one would answer this.

Let $\alpha_g$ be the thermal expansion coefficient of glass. This is the statement that the length $L$ changes with $T$ (are we meant to assume the cross-sectional area of the tube remains constant at $A$? Why is this a good assumption if $L$ changes?) as $\alpha_g = \frac{1}{L}\left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial T}\right)_P$.

For a mercury-in-glass thermometer, we want the fixed $N$ mercury to expand (when $P$ held constant) to some new volume $V$ when the temperature $T$ is raised in such a way that it keeps with out calibration. I think, given the information, we are intended to assume that the volume of the thermometer changes as
$$A\Delta L = L\alpha_g\Delta T.$$
But from here I can't tell what the relevant constraint is? I know that the mercury's volume will change as
$$\Delta V = V\alpha_{Hg}\Delta T.$$
But how do I relate this to the markings on the thermometer?

Comment: To the first approximation, over a small temperature range, the scale will be linear.

Comment: @Farcher Can you explain how I can see that given what I've developed?

Comment: The implication is that a linear change in the Hg and separately a linear change the glass results in a linear change of the combined system.

Comment: @JonCuster Doesn't the relative magnitude of those changes matter?

Comment: No, the combination of two linear changes is still linear.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. If $x = \Delta T$ and the volume in the glass and the volume of mercury obey $4x$ and $2x$ respectively, don't we have a problem? @JonCuster

Answer (score 0):

You will see, in the course of my answer, that nobody should be bothering to perfect such a thermometer. If you want better precision, you simply use better thermometers. If you do not mind taking months to take temperature data, gas thermometer is a rather interesting and important one to learn about.

---

Let us start with some nitpicking. You wrote that
$$\Delta V=V\alpha_\text{Hg}\Delta T\tag{too crude}$$
and you should see that it disagrees with the very previous statement of yours
$$\Delta L=L\alpha\Delta T\tag{better, but still crude}$$
because if this were true, then we should have
$$\Delta V=V\left(\alpha_\text{Hg}\Delta T\right)^3\tag{bad maths consequence}$$
and you can see how stupid this relation is. Instead, the correct way is to define the bulk modulus:
$$\Delta V=V\beta_\text{Hg}\Delta T\qquad,\qquad\beta\approx3\alpha\tag{still approximating}$$
and even for the glass, which is an amorphous solid so that its bulk modulus should be very nicely related to its linear thermal expansion coefficient (for crystalline solids sometimes the different directions could expand differently).

---

You wrote down that
$$\alpha=\frac1L\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial T}\right)_P\qquad\implies\qquad L\approx L_0\,e^{\alpha(T-T_0)}$$
for some reference length and temperature pair. It is from this expression that you can see that $\beta\approx3\alpha$, that is, it is $\left(1+\alpha\Delta T\right)^3\approx1+3\alpha\Delta T\approx1+\beta\Delta T$ that is physically present, so the above ``paradox" really is just a misuse of approximations.

---

When making such a thermometer, one way to think about it is to have a fully solid glass thermometer, then removing the centre, bore hole and the big reservoir, and filling the reservoir with some liquid, vacuum, and then sealing. Now, nobody is really ever going to drill the glass; instead, we extrude the glass so that the bore hole and all is automatically there. I am just talking about conceptually removing the centre.

The reason for thinking so, is that, this glass shell, expands upon heating. It expands both outside and inside. A good approximation would be to think of the removed part as if it were still there, and think of how much expansion it would do upon heating. That would be the approximate expansion of the volume available to the liquid. Note that this is also an approximation. The linear approximation here is just us chopping the Taylor's expansion.

The liquid will also expand, linearly, and even if we compensate the linear nonsense from the above, we will see that all it does is to change the linear expansion coefficient. There will just be some linear expansion coefficient, just nice to set and fix. You can kind of say that, when we pick just two points and carve out set divisions, what we are doing is to empirically measure the linear expansion coefficient and fitting a straight line to those two points.

---

Now we talk about the problems. First of all, the vacuum will not be pure. Even if you could manage to make a pure vacuum, the liquid will evaporate and fill it with pressure. Mercury vapour pressure is low, but it is still a problem. And the volume at the top of the column is a small finite size, so this pressure is actually going to be an issue, because it would fluctuate wildly. Note that this is an incredibly annoying problem, because the definition of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are in terms of constant pressure.

And we had already emphasised that we had been taking a Taylor's expansion. Either the expansion coefficient varies with temperature, or you take higher orders of the expansion, and you should get a lot of corrections.

The length of the glass column itself will expand. We typically carve the glass at one fixed temperature, so the spacing at that temperature will differ from actual usage at other temperatures. How would you take this into account?

You also noted that the area of the bore hole v.s. the length will be important. The size of the reservoir is actually a bigger problem.

You can also never get a perfect bore hole. Everything has imperfections and uncertainties. Even if you design a perfect shape, how would you realise it in a physical product?

---

Instead, what people do, if they need more precision and accuracy, is to put in more calibration reference points. Or use another thermometer that is better suited for the precision needed. Have you tried a platinum resistance thermometer? If you do not even care about precision, a crappy thermocouple is also available.